# integration cannot work with a specific function

Tags: python, plot, integral

I've tried to solve some equations to plot graph.
However, if I use the codes below, I am not able to plot it correctly. It gives `x=y` function even if I changed some parameters in the function.
I already tried the simple function `x`, but the result was correct.

My questions are:

- Function `x` is working (return 2 from 0 to 2), but the `E(z)` is not. what is wrong? It should be different from 2 at 2.
- Did I make any mistakes here?
- I already compared my integration results with wolfram alpha but wolfram alpha did not show `y=x` function.

---

```
def E(z) :
    return (1/((m*(1+z)**3)+(r*(1+z)**4)+l+(k*(1+z)**2)))**(1/2)           

import numpy as np                                                     
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt                                        
import scipy.integrate as integrate                                         
z = np.arange(0,10,0.0001)                                                  
m = 0.3
r = 0
l = 0.7
k = 1-m-r-l
y0 = 0
ys = []
for i in range(100000) :
    ys.append(integrate.quad(E,0,z[i])[0])
ys = np.array(ys).flatten()
L = (1+z)*(ys*(1))
plt.plot(z, L/(1+z), linestyle='--', linewidth=2, label=r"$Taylor$")
plt.legend( loc='upper right', numpoints = 3 )
plt.xlim(0.0, 10)
plt.ylim(0.0, 2)
plt.xlabel(r"$z$",fontsize=18)
plt.ylabel(r"$(v_rec)/c$",size=18)
plt.show()
```

Comment: Are you calling the E(z) function somewhere? If you are not calling it anywhere, changing the code inside it won´t change anything in the outcome.

Comment: What do you mean that `E(z)` is not working? What happens when you run your code? How does that differ from what you want?

Answer (score 0):

looks plausable to me

`plt.plot(z, E(z), 'r')`

[image]